# Firefox OR Chrome separate cookies for different domains

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, cookies

As you might have noticed that when you log in to your `Google Account` on any one of its websites, you are automatically logged in everywhere. Let's say you log into your **Gmail** account (gmail.com) to check your mails, then you are automatically loged in to **youtube** account.

I guess the cookies are shared across the domains. Is there any way to separate the cookies for 2 different domains? I found `MultiFox` and `CookieSwap` for firefox, but it requires you to switch the cookies manually.

any idea?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?  What is your real problem?

Comment: I have different `youtube` accounts that I don't want to connect with my gmail accounts

Comment: I really doubt Google would like that...

Comment: The cookies are not shared, they stay on the same domain (cookies cannot be share across SSL domains due to security, all modern browsers will block this). Both YouTube and Gmail access the same domain to authenticate the user. This is a part of the single signin standard.

Comment: You could try [multiple profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) in Firefox. Use the existing (current) profile as usual, and open the second profile to independently browse sites that may be linked to sites in the current window/tabs. [Multiple profiles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Multiple_Firefox_Profiles), [Command line options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options)

Comment: You can use different accounts for chrome....I mean offline accounts...Switching between them is breeze and they don't share cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a `better than nothing` solution, It's an extension for `Chrome`, its just a very quick to login. Its called [quick login](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-login-for-google-ac/cbgngpehipfmfmpjmhonhacgbkjpdidp?hl=en).

**Note:** Every time you switch your account, it will log you out and then login to the site.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution for cookies isolation is to use different user profiles
to access the websites that you wish to isolate, with differing desktop shortcuts
per-profile.

For Firefox, you have already found the [Multifox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multifox/) extension that allows
connection to websites using different user names simultaneously, although manually.

For Chrome, a better site isolation mechanism is built-in,
currently in various stages of development or experimentation.
See these articles :

[The Chromium Projects - Site Isolation](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/site-isolation)
[The Chromium Projects - Isolated Sites](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/isolated-sites)
[30 days with isolated apps in Chrome](http://netsekure.org/2012/03/30-days-with-isolated-apps-in-chrome/)

I have personally never tried Site Isolation, but as all Google websites are in the google.com domain, I have some doubts.

From the article [Sibling domains cookies isolation](http://mixedbit.org/blog/2012/11/05/sibling_domains_cookies_isolation_.html) :

> Sibling domains are subdomains that share a common suffix which is not
>   a public suffix. Mozilla maintains a list of [public suffixes](http://publicsuffix.org/) that
>   is used by Firefox, Chrome and Opera. IE has its own list.
>
> Browsers implement weaker isolation policy for sibling domains than
>   for completely separate domains: a site can set cookies for its
>   siblings.

Chrome's Site Isolation seems like your best bet and my last link contains an example
of how to set it up, but I do not know whether this will override sibling domains.

Comment: I've tried that, it made somesort of redirect through `google.com`,so it didn't work very well. I'll try to take a deeper look into it during the week

Comment: Well, a desktop shortcut is also single-click ...

Comment: @harrymc Google doesn't use public suffixes for YouTube.  YouTube isn't even on [the list](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1).  Public suffixes have to do with the top-level domain (for example, connecting blogspot.com with blogspot.be and blogspot.ca).  Instead, Google directly runs the Single Sign-In through the google.com domain.

Comment: @philipthegreat: Different profiles do ensure total separation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no perfect way to go about what you want to do.  The problem you're running into is that Google has moved to a Single Sign-On feature across all Google sites.  You haven't been able to "separate cookies" for the different domains because the Google is using *the same domain* across all of those sites for authentication.  There is nothing to separate.  This includes YouTube.

Here are your options.

1. Use [multiple sign-in](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977?hl=en)

   While signed in on a Google account, click on your profile picture in the top bar.  This will give you options to view your profile, add an account, or sign out.  Click on `Add account`, then sign in with your other account.  You don't have to worry about the two accounts sharing information because `"Multiple sign-in does not merge account data, and it does not give one account access to another."`

   When you're wanting to use a different account, simply click your profile picture in the top bar again.  The second account will be listed; simply click on the account you want to use.
2. Use different browsers

   Since Google's Single Sign-in is **browser-specific**, you can easily circumvent it by using a different browser.  You could use Google Chrome for your normal browsing and switch over to Firefox for YouTube.  In that way, you could be signed in in both places without any overlap.
3. Sign out and sign into the other account

   I believe this is what you're doing right now.  It is 100% effective, even if it is annoying.

Comment: Different profiles do ensure total separation.

Answer (score 0):

Use '**Incognito**' mode. This is what can help you I guess. This way you can use different accounts at the same time in your single browser, but different windows.